# Queue delay , sending an email at a certain time

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, laravel-5.3

What want to achieve is to send and email , at a chosen time (by the user)
so my approach was to calculate the time difference then make that the delay time on a queue.

but it seems it's not working as i expect 
all emails get delivered together and not at the right time

**Controller**

```
    public function notifyme($add)
{

    $created = Carbon::now()->addMinutes($add);
    $now = Carbon::now();

    $days = 1440*$created->diff($now)->days;
    $hours = 60*$created->diff($now)->h;
    $minutes = $days + $hours + $created->diff($now)->i;

    $user = Auth::user();


    $user->notify((new notifyme($user))->delay($minutes));

     return redirect('/notif');
}
```

**route**

```
Route::get('notifyme/{add}', 'HomeController@notifyme');
```

**.env**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER="database"
```

im using laravel 5.3 so the `notifyme` controller implements the ShouldQueue contract.

now when i run `php artisan queue:work` or `php artisan queue:listen` and test this
the email sending is delayed, but when i do it again, (while the first job is still delayed) both emails get sent together immediately or after sometime (not at the right time $add)

Any idea what is wrong here? 
is there a better approach? like using a schedule? or what?

Comment: What service you are using for delay,there has an message on laravel that "Note: The Amazon SQS service has a maximum delay time of 15 minutes."

Comment: im using local envirment

Comment: it's not about environment,it's about which driver you are using.You will found this on config/queue.php

Comment: oh sorry, im using database driver, i already mentioned that in the post ! im referencing it using .env file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of approach can be followed to achieve Queue delay for sending an email is to use Laravel inbuilt Mail function with queue facility.
You can take reference from [Laravel Delay Mail Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#queueing-mail)

EG:

```
 Mail::later(5, 'emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
//
});
```

5 is delayed seconds.

Comment: im using laravel 5.3 notification system, and planning to add sms functionalitie too therefor this wont be a good aproach i think in my case

Comment: Ok, so for any delayed functionality, you can try creating job in laravel.
refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#delayed-jobs
 
and dynamically set the queue delay value under job class.

Hope this may help you

Comment: well im not sure if i should mark this as the answer or not, but i thought i delay time is counted in minutes and not seconds. every works fine now. thanks